# make site 100% in height on mobile phone and stop it from scaling up when switching from portrait to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, height, meta-tags, viewport

I have a horizontal site and I want the site to always be 100% in height when viewed on a  mobile device. I have set the viewport meta tag to -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, user-scalable=no">
```

which works fine on both portrait and landscape mode, however when I rotate the phone from portrait to landscape mode the site scale bigger than 100%. Unless I re-load the page (refresh won't work).

I found this link which explained why it does that - http://filamentgroup.com/examples/iosScaleBug/ 
and followed the instruction there and changed the meta tag to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no,  maximum-scale=1.0">
```

This solved the orientation problem when switching from portrait to landscape mode but it doesn't scale the site to 100% height.

It's okay to disable the zoom functionality because I prefer to have zoom off.

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but when trying to achieve what you are I tend to use the following code.

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,    width=device-width"/>
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
```

Hope that helps